# Call a method inside the model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've defined a function called hash_swap inside the User model, but when  I call it it always says Method not found. How could I call a function inside the model ?

Comment: can you show your actual definition and how you're trying to use it? you might be trying to call it on a class when its defined on an instance or vice versa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to call it on the class layer:

```
Model.hash_swap
```

you'll have to define the method as class method.

```
def self.hash_swap
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're calling a function thats been declared inside the model, WITHIN the model then its straight-forward.

```
hash_swap
```

will call the function. (Ofcourse I'm assuming you don't have any parameters.)

It would be more helpful if you pasted your User model here.